# PHP PDO - Get same field name values of three tables in join

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
query = SELECT * FROM design_trip,meal_pref,types where design_trip.meal_id = meal_pref.meal_id and design_trip.triptype_id = types.type_id;
```

There is two columns called "name_en", when i write in foreach

```
<?php echo $value->budget; ?>
```

its getting just first table value.

I'm using this in PDO query to get values from 3 table join, how can i print this values separately?

Comment: Your way of writting join is deprecated since about 25 years.

Comment: `There is two columns called "name_en"` - then you will have to use alias name to remove ambiguity.

Comment: So, didn't say or do anything with either comments or answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give separate names when selecting for the fields. Like

```
SELECT design_trip.meal_id as designtripmealId 
FROM design_trip,meal_pref,types
where design_trip.meal_id =  meal_pref.meal_id 
and design_trip.triptype_id = types.type_id;
```

To get all the fields incase you don't want to specify the rest of the fields, you can use `table_name.*`.

Comment: This looks like a cross join with only filtered rows to simulate it like an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

try this

SELECT * FROM `table1`
JOIN `table2` ON `table1`.`userid` = `table2`.`userid`
WHERE `table1`.`userid` = 1

Comment: This looks like a cross join with only filtered rows to simulate it like an inner join.

Comment: You still need to make it relevant with the context of the OP's query.